# regex (notepad++) find a string that does not start with xx AND contains zz

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ (2015.01.10) on PHP UTF-8 files.

I need to find strings that DO NOT start with `__('`

*and*

contain Polish diacritical vowels, such as: `ą`,`ę`,`ś`,`ć`

or

consonant combinations that are specific to Polish (as opposed to English), such as: `cz`, `sz`

The purpose in general is to find all places in PHP code where plain Polish text have been used and that have not yet been surrounded with proper `gettext` functions.

In other words, i want to find all strings like for example:

```
polish-text-to-be-translated-containing-ą
```

and not

```
__('polish-text-to-be-translated-containing-ą', true)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not trivial, but as long as you don't have lines that contain both translated and untranslated text at the same time, you could search for

```
^(?:(?!__\().)*(?:[ąęść]|[cs]z)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of line
(?:       # Match the following group:
 (?!__\() # Unless the text "__(" can be matched,
 .        # match any non-linebreak character
)*        # any number of times.
(?:       # Then match the following group:
 [ąęść]   # Either one of these letters
|         # or
 [cs]z    # cz or sz
)         # End of group, no repetition necessary (one match is enough)
```

Comment: Tim, thank you very much! Your answer got me on the right track immediately. Will check and confirm.

Comment: I used it effectively and expanded on it. It works perfectly for me. Thank you again Tim for you time!